# VBA Code is only saving 1 of 2 sheets in my new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am taking data from multiple sheets, massaging it so that the data can be loaded in to our website. The data is placed on to two sheets. My VBA code is only saving down one of the two sheets in my newly created workbook. Not sure why?

The only code i am aware of to save down a newly created spreadsheet is the only thing i have tried.

'Create Output file

```
Dim newWB As Workbook, currentWB As Workbook
Dim newA As Worksheet, newP As Worksheet, currentS As Worksheet
Dim strFullname As String

strFullname = "G:\CMG\DCM\Operations\Fusion (Website)\" & Format(Range("CurrentDate"), "yyyy") & "\" & " MonthlyImport" & " " & Format(Range("CurrentDate"), "mmddyy") & ".csv"

Set currentWB = ThisWorkbook
Set currentS = ShOutput '(this is the name of my worksheet)
ShOutput.Range("A:F").Select
Selection.Copy

Set newWB = Workbooks.Add
    With newWB
        Set newA = newWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
        newA.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

       ShOutput.Activate
       ShOutput.Range("H:L").Select
        Selection.Copy

       newWB.Worksheets.Add
        Set newP = newWB.Sheets("Sheet2")
        newP.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

        'Save in CSV
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        newWB.SaveAs Filename:=strFullname, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        newWB.Close
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End With
```

I am expecting a single workbook with two sheets of data

Comment: You can't save a CSV with two sheets.

Comment: .CSV files don't have *sheets*, so you can't save more than one into the .csv file. If you need to save more than one, then you need to save to multiple .csv files (one for each sheet) or combine the data all into one sheet to save to one .csv

Answer (score 1):

As BigBen commented, saving in `xlCSV` format will only save the active sheet.

If you want to save all sheets together, you will need to save as a Workbook by either omitting FileFormat (which will save in the format of the version of Excel being used), or by specifying one of the Workbook formats.

Alternatively, if you want to save both sheets as separate CSV's then you'll have to loop through each sheet, making it active and then you can save the workbook as `xlCSV` format, giving it a different name each time.

See this previous answer for example code https://stackoverflow.com/a/32131048/845655